# How do I change codeigniter existing login system using 3rd party authentication system

Tags: php, codeigniter

I really need help in making modifications to a script I purchased which was designed using codeigniter (a system I am totally new to). The project is designed to have only two user roles with fixed permission (admin, others(is_logged_in)). After couple of hours of learning how MVC works I have been able to change so little yet insignificant stuff in project.

My big problem is this:
I want to use the script to complete a web POS app which I have been working on basically in native php, the project uses ion-auth for the login systems and authentications, please I want to use another 3rd party acl systems like flexiauth, oauth, Aauth, etc but I don't have enough knowledge to know what files I will be replacing and which controller (s) I will need to made modification in.....I am totally stuck....please help me

What I need is simple enough:

I want to have multiple groups and users with access to different resources in the web app e.g a cashier (should have access to pos, customer, report daily_sales, close register, print invoice) AND (an account should have access to dashboard, reports, order etc), manager should be able to create new user, view sales, void sales etc, AND admin should of course have overall access.

What I have now is admin(full access to all the resources) other logged_in users: restricted in some areas.

Groups I have is 2:

```
Admin
Staff.
```

I don't know how to continue.

i think i find the custom library used to define the access
Please check the follow code and advice on where i can start:

```
 class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    define("DEMO", 0);
    $this->Settings = $this->site->getSettings();
    $this->lang->load('app', $this->Settings->language);
    $this->Settings->pin_code = $this->Settings->pin_code ? md5($this->Settings->pin_code) : NULL;
    $this->theme = $this->Settings->theme.'/views/';
    $this->data['assets'] = base_url() . 'themes/default/assets/';
    $this->data['Settings'] = $this->Settings;

    $this->loggedIn = $this->tec->logged_in();
    $this->data['loggedIn'] = $this->loggedIn;

    $this->data['categories'] = $this->site->getAllCategories();

    $this->Admin = $this->tec->in_group('admin') ? TRUE : NULL;
    $this->data['Admin'] = $this->Admin;

    $this->m = strtolower($this->router->fetch_class());
    $this->v = strtolower($this->router->fetch_method());
    $this->data['m']= $this->m;
    $this->data['v'] = $this->v;

}

function page_construct($page, $data = array(), $meta = array()) {
    if(empty($meta)) { $meta['page_title'] = $data['page_title']; }
    $meta['message'] = isset($data['message']) ? $data['message'] : $this->session->flashdata('message');
    $meta['error'] = isset($data['error']) ? $data['error'] : $this->session->flashdata('error');
    $meta['warning'] = isset($data['warning']) ? $data['warning'] : $this->session->flashdata('warning');
    $meta['ip_address'] = $this->input->ip_address();
    $meta['Admin'] = $data['Admin'];
    $meta['loggedIn'] = $data['loggedIn'];
    $meta['Settings'] = $data['Settings'];
    $meta['assets'] = $data['assets'];
    $meta['suspended_sales'] = $this->site->getUserSuspenedSales();
    $meta['qty_alert_num'] = $this->site->getQtyAlerts();
    $this->load->view($this->theme . 'header', $meta);
    $this->load->view($this->theme . $page, $data);
    $this->load->view($this->theme . 'footer');
}

}
```

Comment: did you find out where/how users and groups are stored? I would start from there.

Comment: Yes. Users and groups are store in the db.....groups. I can add new users and but I can only assign users to either of the two groups admin  or staff

Comment: Ion auth library is made that way that you can make as many groups as you need. But if you need to use any other authentication library you should remove any code related to Ion auth and implement other wanted library following documentation.

Comment: also the plugins used are basically datatables, bootstrap, etc.....there is no login auth in the plugin.....but any authentication i have figured out so far call ->ion_auth so i think that is the file use for auth......and considering the user and group definition in this same file(ion_auth) i think i has so much to do with Authentication but am not sure about Permissions.....Also i have access to db and i am using navicat to explore it....i can understand all the table in the db perfectly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter doesn't come with native login system, so the script you purchased is already using a third party package/plugin.

Look for login script code in the following locations : **Models, Libraries**.
The controller is where you control everything, so you can have a look at that later, first you need to determine which files are being used as the core of login functionalities. Once you have determined, you can look at the code and understand how they are handling user groups/ previlages etc.

About the groups and previlages, either they have their on table in database where the values are stored for admin, public etc or the values are stored in a config file, you can find all the config files in the application\config directory. Use PHPMYAdmin to check database and check non codeigniter config files too.

Comment: Please check the code i updated in the code maybe you could advice me on how you think i can start....The problem i have is i could not find class $data[admin] and $data[logged_in] in 'tec' 'site' according to the code.....help me further please

Answer (score 0):

Check the Auth in every controller. Remove them and put your exiting auth system.

Comment: How do I then define permissions and  accesses to different area of the web app.....do I have to do that in every controller....... Only two options are available, check if user is in admin group----> load full site, check if user is logged_in----->load site restrict some area...... The funny thing is that I don't even know where/how many places this is check....